# Bootstrap css navbar not showing fully on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

I am trying to make my navbar fully show on mobile, currently it only shows the "navbar-brand" item.
Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #757070; ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: #ffff; font-size: xx-large; font-family: Inter;" href="index.html">Metal Arte</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " style="color: #ffff ; font-size: x-large; font-family: inter;"
             href="historia.html">Nossa história</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" style="color: #ffff ; font-size: x-large; font-family: inter;" 
            href="#">Conheça nossos serviços</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" style="color: #ffff ; font-size: x-large; font-family: inter;"
             href="contato.html">Entre em Contato</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm try to answer your question. In your code, make sure you import Bootstrap JS to your project.

```
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

After that, try again run your project. Thank you

Comment: Hello! Thanks for trying to help me out, I already have it imported. Currently to temporarily solve this problem I am using a button to make the items show up. Might aswell keep it that way if I cant find out how to do it the way I originallly intended. Its not ugly at all but but the design will be different from the prototype I presented to my clients